# Use Categories Path for Product URLs not working

Tags: magento-1.4, product-urls

I have set "`Use Categories Path for Product URLs`" to "`No`", but still on frontend I am seeing product urls with category paths. 
Checked attribute value on store level also, and it is set to "No" as required.
I have performed re-indexation and cleared cahe (both Magento and browsers). 
I am using Magento 1.4.2.0

UPDATE 
When I am looking at product collection, it is not having any attirube named `"request_path"` instead it is showing `"url_path"`. 

Please let me know if it was a default magento bug in this version or I am missing something. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your collection add the rewrites? As this when the `request_path` should be added? Also are the products saved with the urls wrong?

Comment: @DavidManners There is issue in coding someone has loaded product object inside product collection loop on category page and request path is not present in loaded product object.

Comment: So did you fix this issue? Might be good to share the solution if you have

Comment: @DavidManners: I have added answer which worked for me.

Comment: can someone help me with this ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/81946/getting-infinite-loop-on-loading-category-pages?noredirect=1#comment107263_81946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in coding, someone has loaded product object inside product collection loop on category page and request path is not present in loaded product object.

I wrote custom code to create url.

```
$urlVal = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/seo/product_use_categories'); 
if($urlVal == 0) {
$customProductUrl = $this->getBaseUrl() . $_product->getUrlPath();
} else if ($urlVal == 1) {
$customProductUrl = $_product->getProductUrl();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make a Product URL Reindex

```
Admin Panel -> System -> Index Management -> Catalog URL Rewrites : Reindex data
```

If you have acces over ssh you can make reindex in terminal

```
magento_path/shell/ php indexer.php --reindex catalog_url
```

After make reindex you can empty all cache (just in case)

```
Admin Panel -> System -> Cache Management -> Flush Magento Cache/ Flush Storage Cache
```

Comment: I have already performed re-indexation and flushed cache.