# Getting infinite loop on loading category pages

Tags: category, magento-enterprise, url

After I put my magento project on a linux server. I cleared all of cache. I removed all of the files from var/cache.  I used this command

```
php -indexer --reindexall
```

everything was reindexed successfully. I even truncate the core_url_rewrite and did a new reindex all, BUT I still **cannot** access the **subcategory urls**. The category url I can access.

It might be worth to mention subcategories are actually a category + Amasty layered navigation filters in the URL

I selected NO for the **Use Web Server Rewrites** input, but still i get the infinite loop. So why do i get the infinite loop (for page loading) for subcategory urls ? Thx in advance !

Comment: in mage_core_config make sure you are using the correct domain name ( with www or none www)

Comment: i don't have any table named mage_core_config

Comment: Sorry, it should be core_config >> web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url

Comment: @AhmedElAwadi Yeah I am using the  right urls.

Comment: I have similar redirect loop issue when I upgraded Magento from EE1.9 to EE1.14 and enabled Redis cache. The issue was due to wrong configuration of redis cache, redis needs to be put on different port. Hosting providers solved the issue for me.

Comment: @AnshuMishra I am not familiar with redis cache. I did an upgrade from 1.8 to 1.9. Can you tell me more about the configuration ?

Comment: @Chester Sorry, I don't know what the hosting and our server team has done exactly. But they have changed the redis instance on server. Something like this. It would be great if you can discuss this issue with linux team and hosting team.

Comment: @AnshuMishra I disabled the redis cache module . But it is the same ... any idea ?